# Why is swap not good when using a SSD?

Tags: server, storage, vps, solid-state-drive

On Digitalocean I came up with this message when I want to add swap:

*Although swap is generally recommended for systems utilizing traditional spinning hard drives, using swap with SSDs can cause issues with hardware degradation over time. Due to this consideration, we do not recommend enabling swap on DigitalOcean or any other provider that utilizes SSD storage. Doing so can impact the reliability of the underlying hardware for you and your neighbors. This guide is provided as reference for users who may have spinning disk systems elsewhere.
If you need to improve the performance of your server on DigitalOcean, we recommend upgrading your Droplet. This will lead to better results in general and will decrease the likelihood of contributing to hardware issues that can affect your service.*

Why is that? I thought it was necessary for creating a stable server (not running into memory issues)

Answer (score 9):

I believe that [here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652337/why-no-swap-partitions-on-ssd-drives) your answer.

> Early SSDs had a reputation for failing after fewer writes than HDDs. If the swap was used often, then the SSD may fail sooner. This might be why you heard it could be bad to use an SSD for swap.
>   Modern SSDs don't have this issue, and they should not fail any faster than a comparable HDD. Placing swap on an SSD will result in better performance than placing it on an HDD due to its faster speeds.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is referring to the fact that SSDs have a relatively limited lifetime measured in number of times data is written in each memory location. Although such number has gotten big enough that using SSD as storage drives should not be a concern anymore, Swap memory, as a backup for ram memory, can potentially be written on pretty frequently, thus reducing the overall life of the SSD.

Comment: When swap is not often used it could still be a big benefit when it is needed. What happens when the SSD degrades on DigitalOcean? I think on AWS if it happens they say that hardware platform is being discontinued and you must stop and re init the ec2 or something to that effect..?

Answer (score 0):

SSD Endurance is measured in so called DWPD units. DWPD stands for Drive full Writes Per Day. For Mobile, Client and Enterprise Storage Market segments DWPD requirements are very different. SSD Vendors usually state warranty as, for example, 0.8 DWPD / 3 years or 3.0 DWPD / 5 years. First example means that writing 80% of Drive Capacity every single day will result into 3 years life-time. Technically you can kill your 480GB Drive (let's say with 1 DWPD / 3 years warranty) within 12 days if to perform non-stop write access at the speed of 500 MB/s.

SSDs show much higher throughput on the one side if to compare with HDDs, but at the same time quite low endurance level. Partially it is due to the media physical structure and mapping. For example, when writing 1GB of user data to the HDD drive - internally physical media will receive around 10% more data (meta data, error protection data, etc.). Ratio between Host Data Amount and Internal Data Amount is called Write Amplification Factor (WAF). In comparison SSD may need to write 4 times more data than received from Host. Pure Random access is the worst scenario, when writing 1GB of Host Data will result into writing 4GB of data to the Internal Flash Media. If to perform only sequential write access WAF for SSDs will be close to 1.0, like for HDDs.

Enabling System swap and its intensive usage (probably due to DRAM shortage) will generate more Random access to the SSD. Endurance will degrade quicker if to compare with disable swap. Unless you are running Enterprise System with non-stop IO traffic to the SSD, I would not expect Swap enablement to affect SSD endurance much. You can always monitor SSD SMART Health parameter called - SSD Life Left. How it is changing in dynamic with/without swap enabled will help to make a decision.